# How To Create Your World WITHOUT Building From Scratch

Tags: science-based, worldbuilding-process, map-making, worldbuilding-resources

I know that there are many questions about where to go to actually build your own world, where you can actually be your own god, totally visualizing your world's geography, geology and climate.

But the thing is, my world is so similar to our Earth that it's not possible for me to rebuild a world from scratch.  Are there any websites where I can find a map of the Earth and alter it in any way I wish?

Comment: I guess it depends on the kinds of modifications you want to do. But judging from your other questions, I guess you'll need a 3D tool, not just a map. Could you specify what you are looking for?

Comment: There are plenty of software that can do just that if you put a little effort (Gimp for example). If that is not what you are looking for than what is it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of procedural generation myself. For less of a hands-on approach to a unique map, a quick Google search for map generation reveals sites such as [donjon that offers tools for various types of generation](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/world/). High enough in detail that it's easy to use as a baseline, yet somewhat plausible in general geography.

For actual earth maps, is the site [mapsofworld.com](http://www.mapsofworld.com/map-of-countries.html) high definition enough, or are you looking for more "realistic" looking maps? If so, maybe [topographical maps section in WikiCommons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Topographic_maps_by_country) is your source.

Comment: Welcome to the site Daealis

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea that occurred to me – if you wanted a world that was geologically plausible on a planet similar or identical to Earth, you could always use the geography of Earth at an earlier time period, or even Earth with a higher/lower sea level. This doesn't allow you to "alter it in any way you wish", unfortunately, but it *would* allow you to browse the various continental configurations throughout the Earth's life and choose the one you like the best.

Geography is a fairly different concern than geology, and you have a lot more freedom in this regard. You can probably draw a political map any way you like, as long as you account for certain reliable factors from human history such as civilisations liking water, political borders being demarcated by natural geographic features like rivers and mountain ranges, and powerful states having a preference for controlling their whole local landmass given the opportunity (e.g "Manifest Destiny" in the US, various attempts to "unify" Europe)

Some resources:

- [A Smithsonian Magazine feature on paleogeographic maps](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/travel-through-deep-time-interactive-earth-180952886/?no-ist)
- [A mobile app illustrating some of the changes the earth has undergone](http://www.ancient-earth.com)
- [View Earth with different sea level](http://calculatedearth.com) (This one is better than others for our purpose because it allows entering crazy numbers, like a 1000m rise in the sea level)